# get_field for a widget value returns null ACF

Tags: custom-field, advanced-custom-fields

I am using `ACF` plugin to add a custom field to my widgets.
After creating the field with the name `mobile_enable`, tried to get the value with the method explained in the ACF docs which is the following:

```
the_field('field_name', 'widget_' . $widget_id)
```

Inside the widget method we can get the `widget_id` like this:

```
public function widget( $args, $instance ) {
   $widget_id = $args['widget_id']
}
```

The problem I am having is that the following code returns null even after enabling the option with the checkbox:

```
$is_mobile_enabled = get_field('mobile_enable', 'widget_' . $args['widget_id']);
var_dump($is_mobile_enabled);
```

Comment: In your last snippet: ```'mobile_enable'``` are you missing a "d"?

Comment: No that is how I defined it 

Answer (score -1):

We can't get the whole picture unless we see exactly where your code has been added and called, but I suggest to check every variables value of this line of code `$is_mobile_enabled = get_field('mobile_enable', 'widget_' . $args['widget_id']);`

- Check the value of `$args['widget_id']`, as if it may be empty.
- Also, it's better to use error_logs instead of var_dump, you can do it something like this `error_log(print_r($is_mobile_enabled,true));`

Comment: Thanks or the reply but I have checked every variable and they are all correct. I will use your method to see if anything new happens